# Concurrent primitives test cases

Tags: c, concurrency

Does anybody have or know where to get test cases for concurrent primitives:

- atomics
- spinlocks
- RW locks

or maybe smbd knows concepts how to implements such test cases? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [atomic_ops distributio](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setvbuf.html)n includes regression tests.  You could probably adapt them to your environment.